# Share views and code between iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, xcode4

Let's say I have two iPhone apps with shared core functionality.

The apps isn't entirely the same but 60% of the views are identical. Is there any good way to use the same code in both projects without having to copy paste?

I don't know too much about what SVN or GIT offers.

Would really appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to approach this.

One way would be to put the core functionality into a framework or library that your individual apps call into.

Another way would be to have a "Shared" code folder and then the two separate projects referring into that Shared code folder and building their own apps from it.

Comment: So I could set up the dependencies to the "shared" code in the build phase tab?

Comment: or you can just drag & drop the "Shared" code into your project and the paths to those files (which you normally don't have to care about) in each of your two projects will refer to the code that's living in the "Shared" folder.

Comment: Both of these solutions will work, but I usually recommend frameworks even though they take a bit more to put together. The reason is that you can version them so that if you decide to change some of the common code, you don't have to worry about the change effecting both projects. But it depends on your code :-)